# How to form a set of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, set

My intent is to have a list with unique dictionaries. For this I have figured out that using sets would be a good option and here is what I have been trying.

Here is what I have been doing:

```
import json
mylist = [{'id':1,'name':'john', 'age':34},{'id':1,'name':'john', 'age':34},{'id':2,'name':'hanna', 'age':30}]
print(mylist[0])
myset = set(json.dumps(mylist[0]))
print(myset)
```

And here is the output

```
{'id': 1, 'age': 34, 'name': 'john'} #actual dictionary element
{'e', 'j', 'h', 'i', ':', '"', 'o', '3', 'n', 'a', '}', '4', ' ', ',', 'm', 'g', '{', '1', 'd'} #dictionary element in set
```

Since we cannot store dictionary objects in a sets I am converting the elements to string first using json.dumps . Basically set is singularizing my dictionary elements. How can I store dictionary elements in a set. I understand we cannot store dict objects in a set hence I am converting them to string 1st and then adding in set.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: Why do you call `json.dumps`?

Comment: Since we cannot store dictionaries in set I am converting dictionary to string using json.dumps. And what I am trying to achieve is , I have a list of 100 dictionaries and I want to get a unique list of elements. So I thought sets would be efficient.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `{'id', '1', 'name', 'age', '34', 'john',...}`?

Comment: yes `[{'name': 'john', 'age': 34, 'id': 1}, {'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30, 'id': 2}]`

Comment: That's what you have, not what you want. Please edit your question to clearly state the following: your current data, your goal, your proposed solution, your attempt at that solution, what went wrong with the attempt, and what you think the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple of tuples should work like so:

```
>>> mylist = [{'id':1,'name':'john', 'age':34},{'id':1,'name':'john', 'age':34},
{'id':2,'name':'hanna', 'age':30}]
>>> myset = {tuple(d.items()) for d in mylist}
>>> myset
{(('name', 'hanna'), ('id', 2), ('age', 30)), (('name', 'john'), ('id', 1), ('age', 34))}

# Converting back to dictionary
>>> [dict(i) for i in myset]
[{'name': 'hanna', 'id': 2, 'age': 30}, {'name': 'john', 'id': 1, 'age': 34}]
```

EDIT:

As @Raymond suggest, perhaps first sorting the tuples like so would be a smart idea.

```
>>> myset = {tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in mylist}
```

Dictionaries are in arbitrary order so sorting it  makes sure the tuples are always the same.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to convert to either a *frozenset* of items:

```
>>> list(map(dict, set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in mylist)))
[{'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}, {'age': 34, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}]
```

or use a sorted tuple of items:

```
>>> [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in mylist])]
[{'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}, {'age': 34, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}]
```

- *dict.items()* gives you a list of key/value pairs.
- We convert to a *frozenset* which is hashable and uses an unordered comparison.
- Alternatively, we convert the list to a *tuple* because it is hashable and sort the input because tuple comparison is ordered while dict items are unordered.
- *set()* eliminates the duplicate entries.
- *dict()* converts the tuple of tuples back into a dictionary.

Hope this helps with your project :-)

Thanks to @niemmi for reminding me that *frozenset()* works here as well as sorted tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `set` consisting of [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) objects:

```
>>> c = set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in mylist)
>>> c
set([frozenset([('age', 30), ('id', 2), ('name', 'hanna')]), frozenset([('id', 1), ('name', 'john'), ('age', 34)])])

# Converting back
>>> [dict(x) for x in c]
[{'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}, {'age': 34, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}]
```

Since `frozenset` is unordered collection you wouldn't need to worry about the ordering.